# Augmenting SVG tag with Shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, html, svg, web-component, shadow-dom

I've been experimenting with HTML5 and SVG; and I'm very new to JavaScript and web development, so there's probably something I'm missing. I am trying to create reusable web components, leveraging some of the new features, such as HTML Imports, Shadow DOM, and extending existing web elements. I have two html files:

### test.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test HTML5</title>
</head>
<body>
  <link rel="import" href="Elements/tank.html">

  <svg width="100%"
       viewBox="0 0 500 500"
       style="border: solid; border-width: thin; stroke-width: 2;">

    <polyline points="0,300 100,300 100,100 250,100 250,150 500,150"
              style="fill:none;stroke:black;stroke-width:3"
              onclick="window.alert('you clicked line')" />
    <svg is="my-tank" x="200" y="350" width="50" height="50"></svg>

  </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

### tank.html

```
<html>
<body>
  <template id="tank">
    <rect fill="red" width="50" height="50"></rect>
  </template>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var tankElement = document.currentScript.ownerDocument.querySelector('#tank');

    document.registerElement('my-tank', {
      prototype: Object.create(SVGSVGElement.prototype, {
        createdCallback: {
          value: function () {
            var root = this.createShadowRoot();
                        
            //Works
            root.innerHTML = tankElement.innerHTML;

            //Doesn't work
            //var tankTemplate = document.importNode(tankElement.content, true);
            //root.appendChild(tankTemplate);
          }
        }
      }),
      extends: 'svg'
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code under the `//Works` comment draws a red rectangle where I'd expect in the SVG drawable space. The code under `//Doesn't work` doesn't draw anything or yield any error.

Screenshot of `//Works`: [image: Works]

Screenshot of `//Doesn't work`: [image: Doesn't work]

I've been testing with Opera 41.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this, since `svg` cannot be a shadow host. Only a limited number of elements can be a shadow host:

`article`, `aside`, `blockquote`, `body`, `div`, `footer`, `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `h4`, `h5`, `h6`, `header`, `main`, `nav`, `p`, `section`, `span`.

So not only `svg`, but also others like `input` or `textarea` cannot have shadow-doms (I'm talking about Shadow-DOM **v1**).

See the definition of the `attachShadow` for the details: https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-element-attachshadow

Note also that:

- `SVGSVGElement` does not implement `HTMLElement`.
- Also heard something about SVG's already containing a shadow-dom in their implementation, and with Custom Elements **v1**
  you may have only one shadow-dom (see here: http://hayato.io/2016/shadowdomv1/).

Why don't you create instead a regular custom-element, which may contain `<svg>` elements inside its shadow-dom?

Comment: The SVG 2 standard specifies the use of shadow DOM for the `<use>` tag.

Comment: I think in other words, you can't have an SVG with as a shadow-dom "host", meaning that it acts as a shadow-root.

FWIW https://jsfiddle.net/w08pxrfc/15/

Comment: I don't understand the difference between a shadow-dom "host" and a shadow-root. From the debug panes it does show "shadow-root (open)". So I would guess a svg tag can support some form of shadow. It will let me manipulate the root using innerHTML but not append child. I am using Shadow DOM to try to encapsulate my custom elements from the document's CSS I plan to introduce later.

Comment: I have attempted to create a custom element `<my-tank>` with the `HTMLElement` prototype and no extends parameter in `registerElement`. The red box shows up when used in the body, but the browser doesn't react when the custom element is placed under an `svg` tag. Maybe custom elements are not supported under an `svg` tag?

Comment: Actually SVG *can* be a shadow host: cf. 1st console screenshot in the question. Indeed Chrome goes beyond the WHATWG spec. This post is interesting but doesn't address the issue which is the improper use or <rect> in the <template>

Comment: @Supersharp: SVG cannot be a shadow host according to the spec, and that's what matters in practice. Chrome still allows all elements to be a shadow host because it implemented v0, and it's trying to make both v0 and v1 to work simultaneously for now. However, other browsers will not make any effort to implement v0, and Chrome will eventually drop it too.

Comment: This assessment looks to be correct. It seems you cannot even create a custom element within an `svg` without a surrounding `foreignObject` tag and the extending of existing `svg` tags seems to work only in Chrome based browsers. The WebComponents.js ployfill for IE also behaves in this way.

Answer (score 2):

It's because in your `<template>`, the `<rect>` element is not inside a `<svg>` tag, so it is not recognized as a `SVGRectElement` but as an `HTMLUnknownElement` instead.

To make it work, just add the `<svg>` tag around:

```
<template id="tank">
    <svg>
        <rect fill="red" width="50" height="50"></rect>
    </svg>
</template>
```

Now you can import the element using `importNode()`, or `cloneNode()`:

```
//Works
var rect = tankElement.content.querySelector('rect').cloneNode();
root.appendChild(rect);
```

---

**Update** Importing mutliple SVG Elements

Put elements in `<g>`:

```
<template id="tank">
    <svg>
        <g>
            <rect fill="red" width="50" height="50"></rect>
            <rect fill="blue" width="25" height="50"></rect>
        </g>
    </svg>
</template>
```

Clone `<g>` with its content:

```
var g = tankElement.content.querySelector('g').cloneNode(true);
root.appendChild(g);
```

Comment: It makes sense that the `rect` tag is not an `SVGRectElement` because it's not within an `svg` tag. I see the rectangle when I put it within one. But I get an awkward double svg tag situation. Is there a better approach for this? Is there a performance hit with having two nested svg tags?

Comment: @JustinHuskic There's no double/nested svg tags if you insert just the <rect>, that you can fetch with `querySelector()`. See example above.

Comment: Excellent.
In the event I would like to clone everything under the first `svg` tag, not just the `rect`, are there javascript calls which could do that?

Comment: You could put them in a <g> tag, and then clone the <g> tag and its content with `cloneNode(true)`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/g

Comment: I am having trouble selecting the `<g>` tag using the `var tankElement`. the `childNodes` property and `querySelector` calls for "g" turn up null. It's like the template node doesn't have children at all.